# Is ImageIO.write buffered?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Should I write

```
BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
ImageIO.write(im, "JPEG", os);
```

instead of

```
ImageIO.write(im, "JPEG", file);
```

I.e. are ImageIO file operations buffered by default or not?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a `File`, the underlying implementation will write directly to a `RandomAccessFile` (created in `"rw"` mode), so no buffering. Specifically, a `FileImageOutputStream` will be used as the `ImageOutputStream`.

Comment: So, should I use BufferedOutputStream for optimization or id doesn't make sense?

Comment: How do you know this? Is it documented? Do you have a reference in the api-source?

Comment: @aioobe: I don't believe it's documented, but it is in the source.

Comment: @Andrey: If you're not running into performance issues, the code for just using a file is probably simpler/cleaner. If you are running into performance issues, then it might be worth investigating. Just make sure you profile the app so that you're addressing real issues.

Comment: @aioobe: `javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on the specific implementation of the `IIORegistry` which I suppose is system dependent.

I would expect it to be buffered, but I suppose you could go with the first option to be completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use BufferedOutputStream (As in ex. 1  mentioned in question).

ImageIo.write is not buffered by default. It depends upon what you pass to it in arguments. In case of File object being passed it won't be buffered write.